# Json object formatting with a groupby

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, grouping

I am trying to format a json object by groupping city name. I am trying to take a separate array and move the items based on found and not found to build a string. I am using javascript/angularjs to achieve this.

My current string

```
CurrentDataFormat = 
[
{"Id":17,"code":"123","cityName":"Los Angeles","startDate":"1/20/2016","endDate":"1/20/2016"},

{"Id":18,"code":"456","cityName":"Chicago    ","startDate":"1/22/2016","endDate":"1/25/2016"},

{"Id":19,"code":"789","cityName":"Los Angeles","startDate":"1/13/2016","endDate":"1/21/2016"}
]
```

I am trying to achieve this format

```
ExpectedDataFormat =

[{
"name":"Los Angeles",
"CityData":
[
{"Id":"17","code":"123","startDate":"1/20/2016","endDate":"1/20/2016"},
{"Id":"19","code":"789","startDate":"1/13/2016","endDate":"1/21/2016"}
]},{
"name":"Chicago",
"CityData":
[
{"Id":"18","code":"456","startDate":"1/22/2016","endDate":"1/25/2016"},
]}

}
```

Logic What am I trying (trying with different data though)

```
var array = [
    { "name": "project1", "url": "picture1-1.jpg"},
    { "name": "project1", "url": "picture1-2.jpg"},
    { "name": "project2", "url": "picture2-1.jpg"},
    { "name": "project3", "url": "picture3-1.jpg"},
    { "name": "project1", "url": "picture1-3.jpg"},
    { "name": "project4", "url": "picture4-1.jpg"},
    { "name": "project3", "url": "picture3-2.jpg"},
    { "name": "project1", "url": "picture1-4.jpg"}
];

var separateArray = [];

$.each(array, function (i, item) {   
    var foundItem = false;
    $.each(separateArray, function (y, newItem) {
        if (newItem.name == item.name) {
            if (!(newItem.url instanceof Array)) {
                newItem.url = [newItem.url];
            }
            newItem.url.push(item.url);
            foundItem = true;
        }
    });

    if (!foundItem) {
     separateArray.push(item);   
    }
});

console.log(separateArray);
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle at jsfiddle.net. So we can understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following code,

```
CurrentDataFormat = [{
        "Id": 17,
        "code": "123",
        "cityName": "Los Angeles",
        "startDate": "1/20/2016",
        "endDate": "1/20/2016"
    },

    {
        "Id": 18,
        "code": "456",
        "cityName": "Chicago",
        "startDate": "1/22/2016",
        "endDate": "1/25/2016"
    },

    {
        "Id": 19,
        "code": "789",
        "cityName": "Los Angeles",
        "startDate": "1/13/2016",
        "endDate": "1/21/2016"
    }
]


var refinedArray = {};

for (i = 0; i < CurrentDataFormat.length; i++) {
    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] ? refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName] : {};

    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].name = CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName;

    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData = refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData ? refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData : [];
    refinedArray[CurrentDataFormat[i].cityName].CityData.push({
        "Id": CurrentDataFormat[i].Id,
        "code": CurrentDataFormat[i].code,
        "startDate": CurrentDataFormat[i].startDate,
        "endDate": CurrentDataFormat[i].endDate
    });
}

var ExpectedDataFormat = [];

for (singleCityName in refinedArray){
    ExpectedDataFormat.push({'name' : refinedArray[singleCityName].name, 'CityData' : refinedArray[singleCityName].CityData});
};
```

`ExpectedDataFormat` is holding your desired output

Working demo at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/eozeg4y1/)

Answer (score 2):

Would this code do what you need ?

```
var newarray = [];

CurrentDataFormat.forEach(function(item){
    if(newarray[item.cityName] != undefined){
      var key = item.cityName;
      delete item.cityName;
      newarray[key].CityData.push(item);
  }else{
    var o = {};
    o.name = item.cityName;
    o.CityData = [];
    o.CityData.push(item);
    newarray[o.name] = o;
  }
});

console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: you have given almost right answer but you missed one thing in the 
    if(newarray[item.cityName] != undefined){
        delete item.cityName;
        newarray[item.cityName].CityData.push(item);
      }
as the user has mentioned cityData will not have cityName.

Comment: this seems to be very generic code and useful but jsfiddle throws error CityData is undefined. so unable mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry, it was the `delete` line. I added it without thinking. Fixed it, so now it works.